# How to create a new feature base on a existing feature which have Lists inside

Tags: python

I want to create a new feature which is based on this feature and there are all lists inside.  How should I do to create the feature which like if there exist one feature like 'email' in list, new feature shows 1, if have 'email' and 'phone' in list, then it shows 2?

[image: This is all the lists inside]

```
conditions = [
    (df['host_verifications'].isin(['email', 'phone'])),
    (df['host_verifications'].isin(['email', 'phone', 'work_email'])),
    (df['host_verifications'].isin(['phone'])),
    (df['host_verifications'].isin(['phone', 'work_email'])),
    (df['host_verifications'].isin(['email']))
    ]

values = ['email', 'phone', 'work_email', 'email']
```

Now I tried to create the conditions which include all the possible lists in the 'host_verifications' feature and create values list as I want to assign for the lists in conditions. I want to let new feature could show 1 if include one element in values list, show 2 if have two elements, 3 if have three elements. Is there any way could do this? Should I use if else?

Comment: So do you want to assign individual ids to different values in the column? Have you tried something like https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html ?

Comment: I want to create new feature to show 1 when it assigned to the existing feature which have 'email' or 'phone' or 'work_email', shows 2 when the existing feature have 'work_email' and 'phone' or 'email' and 'phone', something like that. @Damian Robert

Comment: You could use apply on `host_verifications` column: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

And then write a python lambda function that checks if the elements you want are in the array or not for every row, and assign integers depending on that